# Flicker issue on hover: because of transform

Tags: css, hover, transform

`:before` has covered complete `.box` using `position: absolute` so that complete box will be clickable. If I hover anywhere in the `.box` the `a` should get hoverd. This works fine If `transform` is removed. Link has `transform: scale(1.2)` on `:hover`. Which makes it flicker.

If `transform` is removed. Everything works fine. This issue is in chrome and firefox.

```css
.box {
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
}

.box a {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
}

.box a:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.box a:hover {
  background: red;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <a href="#" class="link">Test</a>
  <h3>test</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to find the reason of this issue. However, was able to fine different way to solve the issue.

Added `:after` with same size of `a` and gave hover action to after.

```css
.box {
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
}

.box a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  transition: font-size 0.5s;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: transparent;
}

.box a:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.box a:after {
  content: attr(title);
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #666;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.box a:hover:after {
  transform: scale(1.2);
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <a href="#" class="link" title="View Offer">View Offer</a>
  <h3>test</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is tricky and I'm not sure that I have an answer but we can investigate together.

The first thing we can do is give the pseudo element a background color so that we can visualize what's happening. Let's also move it to the side since the color will cover everything.

```css
.box {
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
}

.box a {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
}

.box a:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 400px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
}

.box a:hover {
  background: red;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <a href="#" class="link">Test</a>
  <h3>test</h3>
</div>
```

When you hover over the pseudo element you'll see that it changes shape and physically moves. This seems to be due to the transform, since pseudo element is a child and will be affected by styles applied to it's parent.

To be more precise, what's happening is a repeat loop of:

1. You hover over the pseudo element
2. Hover animation is applied to parent and child
3. Pseudo element moves out of the way of the cursor
4. Hover animation ends
5. Pseudo element returns to it's original position
6. Back to step one

Transforms seem to create a [new stacking order & context](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#module-interactions). Which is why the positioning of the child element gets reset. Thus far I am unable to come up with a workaround.

A very simple solution would be to get away from this entire subject and wrap the area you want to be clickable into it's own anchor tag.

```css
.box {
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
}

a {
  display: block;
}

a:hover .box {
  background: red;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="link">
  <div class="box">

    <h3>test</h3>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: I can't wrap the .box by <a> as I have other themes which use the same layout. My last option is the do it using JS for current theme. Thanks for your time.